# Is issuer's bank allowed to charge fee when cashing check?

Tags: united-states, check

I have previously heard that if you take check to the issuer's bank; they are required by law to cash the check for the full amount.

Recently I got a check from business but when I took it to their bank "Bank of America" I was told that there will be fee. After not getting anywhere with the teller I asked to talked to manager who ended up telling me that they have to charge fee on checks cashed from business accounts but if it was personal check there would be no fees.

That made no sense to me, but what makes even less sense is the fact that if you show up in person to the bank they charge you a fee, but if I deposit it at my bank there is no fee charged by issuers bank.

Answer (score 4):

Some banks charge their own customers if they make use of a teller. That is what you are doing. You are going to a bank where you are not a customer and requesting a transaction that requires a teller. If you cash the check by going though your bank, the issuer's bank only handles it as a non-teller transaction.

Comment: by why in this case of would it matter if account belongs to business account versus personal? also is this regulated by government in any way?

Comment: @VladimirOselsky- Because they expect businesses to write more checks.  If it were prohibited by the government then they'd just charge fees on a different activity or basis; the regulation doesn't remove the costs of banking.  Why can't you use your bank?

Comment: I was in another city where my bank was not available. I just ended up waiting until I was able to use my bank. More than anything else I refuse to pay another dime to BoA after they charged me arm and a leg in overdraft fees that ended up being major lawsuit against them few years ago.